# Union Multiple Lists with Client JavaScript Object Model

Tags: 2010, jquery, csom, caml, sp.js

I have several SP 2010 lists with the exact same columns. I would like to perform a union on the lists and display a filtered subset from this union.

I tried doing it using a joined datasource in SP Designer, but I believe the large amount of data makes this not possible (SP Designer keeps crashing when I try to add a dataview using my joined datasource.)

So, I'm trying to do it with SP.js - it works great *for one list*, but for some reason I can't seem to make it work for multiple lists. I suspect there is something I don't understand about how the *Initialize* function works.

Anyway, enough preface, here's the code:

```
  var clientContext = null;
  var web = null;
  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Initialize, "sp.js");
  function Initialize()
  {         
    getRegionListData("Migrated 2013");
    getRegionListData("Migrated 2014");
    getRegionListData("Migrated 2011");
    getRegionListData("Migrated 2012");
  }

function getRegionListData(listName)    {

clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = clientContext.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        var q = "<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='aFOS_x0020_Region' /><Value Type='Text'>A2</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>";
        camlQuery.set_viewXml(q);
        this.listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(listItems, 'Include(Id, FACID, Description, aFOS_x0020_Region, EncodedAbsUrl)');
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListItemsLoadSuccess), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) {

    var listItemEnumerator = this.listItems.getEnumerator();
    var cgRes;

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext())        
{
        var item = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var facid = item.get_item('FACID');
var description = item.get_item('Description');
//var afosReg = item.get_item('aFOS_x0020_Region');
var itemId =  item.get_id();
var absUrl = item.get_item('EncodedAbsUrl');
              var url = absUrl.slice(0,69); 
$('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr><td class=wcContainer><a href=' + url + '/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + itemId + '>View</a></td><td class=wcContainer>' + facid + '</td><td class=wcContainer>' + description + '</td></tr>');

}

   var count = this.listItems.get_count();

$('#tdRes').text(count);         
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
itemCount = 0;
runCount = 0;
arrLists = ["Migrated 2011", "Migrated 2012", "Migrated 2013", "Migrated 2014", "Migrated 2015 A - F", "Migrated 2015 G - P"]; 
arrYears = [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2015];

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Initialize, "sp.js");

function Initialize()
{   
  ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  web = ctx.get_web();
  camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
  q = "<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='FACID' /><Value Type='Text'>MS007</Value></Eq><And><Neq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>Closed</Value></Neq><Neq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>Work Complete</Value></Neq></And></And></Where></Query></View>";
  camlQuery.set_viewXml(q);     
  while (arrLists[runCount]) {
  getMigratedListData(arrLists[runCount], arrYears[runCount]);
  runCount++;
}   

function getMigratedListData(listName, listYear)     {
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
    var listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    ctx.load(listItems, 'Include(Id, FACID, Description, EncodedAbsUrl, Request_x0020_ID, Status)');
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {onListItemsLoadSuccess(listItems, listYear);}, onQueryFailed);        
}

function onListItemsLoadSuccess(myItems, listYear) {   
    var listItemEnumerator = myItems.getEnumerator();      
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext())        
   {
       var item = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
       var itemId =  item.get_id();
       var reqId = item.get_item('Request_x0020_ID');
       var facid = item.get_item('FACID');
       var description = item.get_item('Description');
       var absUrl = item.get_item('EncodedAbsUrl');
       var status = item.get_item('Status');
       var url = absUrl.slice(0,69);
       $('#dataTable tr:last').after('<tr><td class=wcContainer>' + listYear + '</td><td class=wcContainer><a href=' + url + '/DispForm.aspx? ID=' + itemId + '>' + reqId + '</a></td><td class=wcContainer>' + facid + '</td><td class=wcContainer>' + description + '</td><td class=wcContainer>' + status + '</td></tr>');
   }

    itemCount = itemCount + myItems.get_count();
   $('#tdCount').text(itemCount );   

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

<table id="countTable" cellpadding="2" width="200px" border="0">
<tr>
<td class="wcHeader">Total Tickets Found:</td>
<td class="wcContainer" id="tdCount">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table id="dataTable" cellpadding="2" width="1200px" border="0" >
<tr>
<th class="wcTH" id="svYear">YEAR</th>
<th class="wcTH" id="svRequest">REQUEST</th>
<th class="wcTH" id="svFacid">FACID</th>
<th class="wcTH">DESCRIPTION</th>
<th class="wcTH">STATUS</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just to clarify: This line was the key to getting it to work:      **ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {onListItemsLoadSuccess(listItems, listYear);}, onQueryFailed);**